# Android Firestore display user data with Uid

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to display user data in the app using user id for retrieval.
The problem is that this code pops out the second option which is that the document referring to the user was not found.

```
        String userUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DocumentReference documentReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(userUid);
    documentReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Données : " + document.getData());
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Pas de données trouvées");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Une erreur est survenue ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });

    documentReference.addSnapshotListener(getActivity(), new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            pseudo.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Pseudo"));
            name.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Name"));
            surname.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Surname"));
            mail.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Mail"));
            age.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Age"));
        }
    });
```

If instead of "userUid" in DocumentReference I use a Uid write directly (for exemple : ZxjVbnC5uodcQC5729sn) it works but with the variable it does not.

**EDIT 1**

Here is a screen of the database :

[DataBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1hzI.png)

If I display it in the logcat I realize that the id retrieve is not the one corresponding to the user.

```
D/Données de l'utilisateur: Pas de données trouvées njo4FfZNQLfHktDRzwfYMjmLO6G2
```

That of the logged-in user is: ZxjVbnC5uodcQC5729sn

And the one found by getUid() is : njo4FfZNQLfHktDRzwfYMjmLO6G2

I don't understand why this is not showing the correct Uid...

Comment: If you try to log the value of `userUid`, what is printed out in the logcat? Please also edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: I edited my question to add everything you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the UID of the logged-in user is different than the one in the database, you get the expected behavior. You cannot get something from a node that actually doesn't exist. Most likely, you used that user earlier, and somehow you deleted the account only from the Firebase Console and you left the corresponding data in the database. The simplest solution would be to write the data again using the current UID. Right after that, your code will work.

Comment: With your answer I tried to recreate a user in order to see if indeed I had modified the old one in some way but that did not change anything and the problem remains the same...

Comment: In that case, please show me the new UID in the database and the result of that log statement to see that it matchs, right?

Comment: Ok after a new search I just noticed that in the authentication section it is indeed the right Uid, like the one found when I ask for the Uid. The problem therefore comes from saving the document which is not done with the correct Uid.

Comment: Your answer was correct, it's just me who missed something in my code, thank you for your help!

Comment: Good to hear that :) You're very welcome, cheers!